# How do I mix two audio files at different times?

Tags: java, audio, mixer

I have two audio files one is 20 seconds long and the other is 10 seconds long. I want to mix the two samples so that the second clip starts playing from second 5 to second 15. How do I do that using Java's Mixer?

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the level of precision you are going for.

A relatively easy thing to code would be to play back the first sound via a `SourceDataLine` from an `AudioInputStream`. With this, unlike with the `Clip` object, you can count the elapsed frames. Include a target frame count corresponding to the amount of time you want to elapse before triggering the second sound. When that frame is reached, call the `start` method of the second sound which can be a `Clip` that is fully ready to go (don't add latency by loading or opening, these things should be done beforehand).

Even so, there might be a bit of variability as to the exact moment the second sound will start relative to the first. The only way I know it nail with frame-level precision is to process both inputs in the same `while` loop, manually converting bytes to PCM, adding the values, then converting back to bytes and shipping to a single `SourceDataLine`.